# Always positioning an item at the top of recycler view

Tags: android

How can I show a particular item in recycler view always at the top?

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final XpertViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        db.collection(XPERT_MASTER_KEY).whereEqualTo("slug","xpert").get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot queryDocumentSnapshot : task.getResult()) {
                                xpert_name= String.valueOf(queryDocumentSnapshot.get("name"));}
                        }
                        if(xpertName.get(position).equals(xpert_name)){
                            holder.itemView.scrollTo(1,1);
                        }

                    }
                });
```

Comment: please ask anything for more information

Comment: are you want to scroll RecyclerView to top position or sticky item for recyclerview
can you explain more about issue ?

Comment: stick a particular item of a list in the top always @RahulMandaliya.thanks for asking.please help me out.

Comment: set header for that item

Comment: @HoàngVũAnh how can I do that can you give any reference thanks.

Comment: you can search google with key word: *set header for recyclerview android*

Comment: you want to show specific data item to top or you  just want scroll to top ?

Comment: @frankenstein show specific data item always at the top. please help me out if you can.

Comment: you list type string or custom class model ? if it is custom class model then can you show me your model?

Comment: @subratasharma Do you want to sort list and show particular item at the top or you just want to add and different item like header at the top. In both case I can help you.

Comment: sort list and show the particular item at the top @Nitish .but like to know other too just for learning thank you for helping me out .

Comment: @subratasharma Please check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what type of list you have. I am assuming you have object type list. Suppose your POJO file name is `Data` and you have a condition to set that item at top. for example Data have a string name title and condition is if title.equals("value")

You can use below code.

```
    for (int i = 0; i< dataList.size(); i++) {
            if (dataList.get(i).title.equals("value")){
                Collections.rotate(dataList, i);
            }
        }
```